# Is there a way to fetch the icon file path of an application using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, alfred

I'm currently writing an Alfred workflow in which I want to retrieve the icon file path linked to an application. Is there any way to do so natively using Apple Script ?

```
tell application "Finder"
    set appPath to POSIX path of (path to application "Terminal")
    set resourcesPath to appPath & "Contents/Resources"
    set contentFiles to (list folder resourcesPath)
end tell
```

Doing that I managed to get a list of file names but now I don't really know how to filter the `.icns` file.

Comment: What have you been able to achieve so far?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Alfred however as far as AppleScript and getting an Application Bundle's Icon's pathname is typically not hardcoded, so it's not like you can get its path with a single command.  Additionally the value of `CFBundleIconFile` can be with and without the `.icns` extension, so when building the fully qualified pathname of the Application Bundle's Icon you'll need to take that into consideration as you write your code.

As an example, using the built-in `/Applications/Calculator.app` the `/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/Info.plist` shows that the *Icon file* is "Calculator.icns" but doesn't give the path, although it will usually be within the Resources folder within the Application Bundle and in this case it's, `/Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/Resources/Calculator.icns`.  So you'd have to get the value of `CFBundleIconFile` from the App's `.plist` file and check whether or not it has the `.icns` extension and test to see if it's in the default location, which it normally is but not always.

So in Terminal you'd query using `defaults`, e.g.:

```
defaults read /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleIconFile
```

In AppleScript you could set the results to a variable and go from there, e.g.:

```
set appIcon to do shell script "defaults read /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleIconFile"
```

It returns: `Calculator.icns`

Where as,

```
defaults read /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleIconFile
```

Returns: `Terminal`

Yet the FQP is `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Terminal.icns`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
do shell script "find " & quoted form of POSIX path of (path to application "Terminal") & " -iname \"*.icns\";"
```